# How to search through a DB using a cursor( sqlite query) in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am an android beginner. I am trying to design this simple application which takes the name of a city from the user using an editText View , compares that in the database , and returns the ZIP code of that city. 
Now ,I'm having a problem with the implementation of cursors. Please help.How can i query the database to fetch the corresponding code.

```
        EditText city;
    Button add,show1;
    RadioGroup choose;
    String k;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try
        {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        city=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        choose=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio01);
        show1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        k=city.getText().toString();
        createDatabase();
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }


show1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db=openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        try{

        if(k == "CITY")
        {
            String[] result_columns=new String[]{"_id","CITY","CODE"};
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, result_columns, 
                    "CITY" +"=?", new String[]{"k"}, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

        String xnewcode=cursor.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(activity1.this, xnewcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cursor.moveToNext();

            //db.close();
        }}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity1.this,"Fault in showing " + e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Specifically, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218395/android-app-which-retrieves-the-zip-code-for-each-city I'm having problems with the whole program. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218395/android-app-which-retrieves-the-zip-code-for-each-city

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select _id,city,code 
      FROM city where city_name like '"+s+"%' order by city", null);
```

s is the your string of enter characters  in search box

use the below links it's very useful in android app development.

http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cursor   mCursor = db.rawQuery("select ZIPCODE from TABLENAME where CITYNAME= ? ", new String[]{"NEWYORK"});
```

hope you got the single result only.

then to get it from(incase of string means) `mCursor.getString(coloumn_id)`

Comment: This solution is fine.. but how to expand this query so that it is applicable to all the cities.. and works for the whole database.

Comment: just get the string from the edittext and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: I'm having problems with the whole program. This is the whole program. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218395/android-app-which-retrieves-the-zip-code-for-each-city

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to get the result in loop

```
String[] result_columns=new String[]{"_id","CITY","CODE"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, result_columns, 
                "CITY" +"=?", new String[]{"k"}, null, null, null);

do {

                        String xnewcode = cursor.getString(0);
                        System.ouot.println("...display the result..."+xnewcode);
                    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
```

Have a look on [Sample project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx)

or

Tutorial on [sqlite database for android](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: I have used a Toast instead of system.out.println command. Will that not work? .. I guess it should.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218395/android-app-which-retrieves-the-zip-code-for-each-city I'm having problems with the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've forgot some checks. However, it really depends on the language in which the cities are written - the SQLite operator "LIKE" is case-insensitive only for English letters. If your cities are in another language, consider storing them in upper/lower case in the database and converting the input string to upper/lower case in java (String.toUpper/LowerCase() ).

```
String[] result_columns=new String[]{"_id","CITY","CODE"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, result_columns, 
                "CITY" +" like '%?%'", new String[]{"k"}, null, null, null);

if(cursor != null)
{
  while(cursor.moveToNext())
  {
    String xnewcode=cursor.getString(1);
    Toast.makeText(activity1.this, xnewcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

You can store all results in an array and show them to the user, asking him to choose the right one.

EDIT: If you are not familiar, the "x LIKE Y" statement compares x to any substring from Y with length = x.length. It's pretty useful, because you can't guarantee that the user will enter the whole city name. So with my example if the user enters "york", the Cursor will return values like "new york", "yorkshire", "york" and so on.

Comment: And could you please guide me.. about how should i use this with an onKeyListener.. as the user will be entering the name of the city in the editText box.

Comment: This is my whole program... This is the main activity file

Comment: i'm providing both the activity files.. please look into it and help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218395/android-app-which-retrieves-the-zip-code-for-each-city

Comment: oh. just replate the contents of your if statement: if(k == "CITY") with the source that I've written. So far you display a Toast to show the post code, but you could use whatever you want.